# Difference between inheritance and composition in a MVC architecture?

Tags: python, class

What is the better choice between the two? I think that they both provide the same solution, but which one is better to choose in an MVC architecture? In the code below, `Parent` class is part of Model and `Child` class is part of Controller:

```
class Parent():
    def parent_function(self):
        print("parent class")

#passing parent as argument
class Child(Parent):
    def child_function(self):
        return super().parent_function()

#referencing parent on __init__
class Child():
    def __init__(self):
        self.parent = Parent()
        super().__init__()
    def child_function(self):
        return self.parent.parent_function()
```

Thank you

Comment: "Both provide the same solution" They don't, and the second one is simply wrong. It doesn't even work, did you try it?

Comment: In solution one, it's a biological `Child` that shares traits with its parents. In solution two, it's an adopted `Child`.

Comment: @timgeb child_function is defined in Child, and it works for both solutions

Comment: In Python `super` has nothing to do with the parent, it calls the next in the Method Resolution Order `__mro__` of the class. And btw your second class does not work as you expected, in fact if you call `child_function` method you will get an `AttributeError`.

Comment: @DeepSpace yes I tried both of them, and even the second one worked

Comment: Why so many downvotes?

Comment: Just because it works doesn't mean it's a good solution. I think in your case you need to revisit how inheritance works, and whether you need it for your classes.

Comment: I doubt it works... [please try it](https://repl.it/NoZR/0)

Comment: @tyteen4a03 I am doing a MVC pattern, so Parent class is in Model and Child class in Controller. I don't know if inheritance would be the best solution for this

Comment: @JohnSmith No. Inheritance should be used if the base class and the derived class are functionally similar but different in details (e.g. `Dog` and `Chihuahua`/`GoldenRetriever`). Models and Controllers do vastly different things.

Comment: @DeepSpace It was a typo, I saw it after Billy posted an answer. Sorry

Comment: @Jose I made a typo on the second one. It's edited now, should be fine

Answer (score 4):

They're not the same thing.

The former uses inheritance, meaning that all methods and attributes from `Parent` is available in `Child`. The latter uses composition, where `Child` instances keep a (private) reference to `Parent`. Inheritance automatically "copies over" the functionality of the base object while allowing for changes in details, but forces the child object to implement the same interface of the parent object. Composition doesn't force this, allowing more flexibility, but managing complex chains of what-composes-what might be a challenge.

No matter which direction you go, they should be used only if the base class and the derived class are functionally similar but different in details (e.g. Dog and Chihuahua/GoldenRetriever). In your comment you said that you wanted to link your models and your controllers in an MVC app, then you only need to hold a reference to the model in the controller class, and call the relevant methods on the model when necessary. Since Models and Controllers are vastly different things, inheritance/composition doesn't make sense here.

(By the way, in the second solution `super()` does nothing as the "parent class" in this case is `object`, not `Parent`.)

Comment: Wrapping hides the interface as you said, but this doesn't mean it is bad, you may want to hide the interface.

Comment: Why would you want to hide the interface of the parent from the child?

Comment: @tyteen4a03 sorry, I made a typo on the second part of the code. I meant `self.parent.parent_function()`. I want to hide the interface because I am using a MVC pattern, as I mentioned in the comment

Comment: @tyteen4a03 Thanks a lot!

Comment: @tyteen4a03 Why would you want to offer all the API from the parent on the children? Both approaches are valid, depends on the design. For example, if I wanted to make a `Rest` class with methods `get`, `post`, ... and then I make a `TwitterRest` class that has methods according to Twitter's API, I don't want the user to be able to do `get` calls as they already have the more abstract methods, and thus wrapping `Rest` class would be a better approach instead of inheritance.

Comment: @Adirio I'm talking about inheritance, not how JohnSmith has (incorrectly) applied it to his problem.

Comment: @tyteen4a03 as this is an answer to the OP, you are just talking about part of the question. He asked about Inheritance vs Composition, with his own words as he didn't know how they were called. You answered about Inheritance. I added in a comment that the hiding of the interface that the composition does, does not need to be considered bad, it's just a different approach.

Comment: @Adirio Models and Controllers are vastly different things - it makes no sense to combine the functionality of these two things together, either via inheritance or composition. Holding a reference to another object in one object does not automatically mean the composition pattern is being used.

Comment: @tyteen4a03 I am getting the data from the model to controller, and then send it to the view. Why doesn't it make sense to use composition here?

Comment: @tyteen4a03 I agree. We didn't have that piece of info when the comment was done (MVC pattern). If that info was on the OP at the start talking about Inheritance and Composition and then telling that none of them fit his use case and propose an alternative would be the perfect answer.

Comment: @JohnSmith You should have 3 classes: `Model`, `View` and `Controller`. The instances will have references to one or multiple intances of the different types, but they represent 3 things. That's the main use of the MVC pattern, splitting the logic from the data and from the representation.

Comment: @tyteen4a03 +1, your answer now covers all the topics.

Comment: @JohnSmith As I said, inheritance/composition only makes sense if the classes are *functionally similar*. Your classes do very different things.

Comment: @tyteen4a03 yes I understand, so I should choose a different way. But what do you mean by `hold a reference to the model in the controller class`?

Comment: @JohnSmith `model = Model()`. `model` is now a reference to an instance of `Model`. It's just a regular variable.

Comment: @tyteen4a03 isn't that in the second part of the code? `self.parent = Parent()` ?

Comment: Yes, however it is not the same as object composition, as the class using the other class is not functionally similar. You also wouldn't be using `super()` calls.

Comment: @tyteen4a03 but `super()` does not make a difference in the second solution, as you also said. So what is then the difference between that(which is composition) and holding a reference?

Comment: @tyteen4a03 then wouldn't the second solution be valid for this case? (without the `super()` call ofcourse)

Comment: Yes, however not in the context of a `Parent` and a `Child`.

Comment: @tyteen4a03 yes ofcourse, that was just the naming convention in the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

They are certainly not the same solution.  Your second example will call `Child`'s definition of `parent_function`, which does not exist in your code, while your first example will call the `Parent` class's definition of `parent_function`, which we presume to exist.

Also in your second example, calling `super().__init__()` has no effect since the only superclass of `Child` is `object`.

It looks like you're asking what's the difference between *composition* and *inheritance*, which is often a matter of personal preference, and often requires answering "is a" vs. "has a" type questions.  A better example of how you would use *composition* rather than *inheritance* to achieve similar functionality would look like:

```
class Child:
    def __init__(self):
        self.parent_obj = Parent()
    def child_function(self):
        return self.parent_obj.parent_function()
```

Comment: oh, I just saw my mistake in the code now, I actually have it as `self.parent_obj.parent_function()` Let me edit the question

Comment: I think you mean object *composition*.

Comment: @John Smith:  Thanks, and judging from your comment on your own question stating that your Parent is a "model" and Child is a "controller", you almost certainly want to use composition rather than inheritance (a model is not a controller, but has a reference to one).

Comment: @tyteen4a03:  Thanks, edited.  Big words and not enough caffeine :).

Answer (score 1):

That is called inheritance vs composition. The difference is basically the scope, with inheritance you have access to every parent attribute or method from the child class directly while in the second case you have to give it access explicitly. Sometimes you may want to hide some part of an objects API so wrapping (composition) is the way to go, other times you just want to extend a base class and inheritance is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You get the same solution by using Inheritance (first) and Composition (second). I prefer second one.